# IPHONE SSL HTTPS was working with http

Tags: iphone, swift, ssl

I have an app that works great using the http. I had to disallow the transport setting of course while I developed.

I got a SSL/TLS (see below) certificate from GoDaddy and want to secure my APP and change my http: to https and get the error attached see image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have correctly installed the certificate on your server, then you don't need to add any exceptions on the iOS app.

ATS (App Transport Security) was introduced by Apple so that your app uses https and not http for your communication with servers. Have a look at [this](http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/) URL for more info if you need to put an exception.

Comment: Let me try again: I set the App transport Security Setting to Dict and Allow Arbibtary Load to true to get the Http: (non s) working. Godaddy installed a certificate with SSL/TLS1.2. What changes are needed i use  do
            {
                urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
                //print("DB_To_Array_Swift#################  0 - dotry")
                while_exit = "YES"
            }